# How can I highlight and individually color the connected components of a graph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have a graph `G`, and I wish to individually highlight and color the different connected components of a graph.  It is simple enough to do this for one component:

```
HighlightGraph[G, ConnectedComponents[G][[2]]]
```

But how does one do this for multiple components?  I'd ideally like to be able to pass a color string to specify each highlighted component, something like `componentColorString = { Blue, Green, Red,...}`.  Is this possible?

Comment: `HighlightGraph[g, Subgraph[g, #] & /@ ConnectedComponents[g]]` will highlight all components, each with a different colour.

Comment: @Szabolcs That's a great command.  Can I also specify or randomize the colour each time I run it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can iterate through the vertex-, and edgelists of connected components:

```
SeedRandom@11;
g = RandomGraph[{15, 20}, DirectedEdges -> True, 
   EdgeStyle -> GrayLevel@.8, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
   VertexSize -> Scaled@.03, ImageSize -> 300, ImagePadding -> 10];
conn = ConnectedComponents[g]
{nodes, edges} = Transpose[{VertexList@#, EdgeList@#} &@Subgraph[g, #] & /@ conn];

SetProperty[g, {
  VertexStyle -> 
    Join @@ Table[Thread[nodes[[i]] -> Hue[i/Length@nodes]], {i, Length@nodes}],
  EdgeStyle -> 
    Join @@ Table[Thread[edges[[i]] -> Hue[i/Length@edges, 1., .7]], {i, Length@edges}]
  }]
```

> ```
>  {{1}, {3, 7, 8, 11, 12}, {2}, {13, 14}, {15}, {4, 9}, {6}, {5}, {10}}
> ```

[image]

The same in a `Manipulate`, showing one connected subgraph at a time:

```
Manipulate[
 SetProperty[g, {
   VertexStyle -> Thread[nodes[[i]] -> Hue[i/Length@nodes]],
   EdgeStyle -> Thread[edges[[i]] -> Hue[i/Length@edges, 1., .7]],
   PlotLabel -> Row@{"component vertices: ", conn[[i]]}
   }],
 {{i, 1, "component #"}, 1, Length@conn, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]